# How To Pass Dates In Zulu Format So They Will Work Regardless Of TimeZone

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, datetime

I'm passing a date into a backend function that performs several processes. I have users reporting that they are getting failures from different time zones (more specifically overseas, but a couple others from the coasts). So I'm trying to format my date/time to ZULU time to allow those users to get success regardless of their time zone.

Below are the formats that I have built to pass into the function to solve the issue. The one that is at 05 hours works fine, but the one that is at 00 (which is what I understand to be timezone agnostic) is failing.

THIS FAILS
1960-08-02T00:00:00:000Z

THIS WORKS
1960-08-02T05:00:00.000Z

Can someone with some date conversion javascript experience tell me why this would be the case?

Thanks,
B

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the *format* of both is different:

```
1960-08-02T00:00:00:000Z
                   ^ colon
1960-08-02T05:00:00.000Z
                   ^ period
```

You should use the latter format (see also [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15)), with which you'll find that `1960-08-02T00:00:00.000Z` will be accepted as well.

Comment: This is it. Syntax... Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Any JavaScript date can be converted to correct UTC (Zulu) format with `toISOString` or `toJSON`:

```
new Date().toISOString();
//"2016-09-30T16:56:51.654Z"
```

Comment: The real hero here is [`Date.prototype.toISOString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString).

Comment: Yep. `toJSON` returns the same thing

Comment: [`toJSON`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toJSON) *calls* `toISOString`. If you were serializing a `Date`, then `toJSON` is more appropriate. If you're simply converting format, use `toISOString`.

Comment: @AndréDion There is really no difference. `toJSON` is just an alias for `toISOString`. They both return a string.

Comment: I disagree. While the output is the same, the semantics around the usage is different. To illustrate, imagine the JSON spec were to change so that dates are now represented as unix time. `toJSON` would then return time in milliseconds since Epoch, and this answer would be invalidated. In this hypothetical scenario, `toISOString` would still return the expected ISO 8601 format.

Comment: Note the UTC is a standard, Z is a military symbol for time zone UTC+0000 that has been adopted by civil users.